# ValidationSummary not working with Login control

Tags: asp.net, validation, authentication

I'm following this walkthrough from Microsoft:
"Walkthrough: Creating a Web Site with Membership and User Login"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(v=vs.100).aspx

My Login control works and authenticates me successfully.  It also shows the little validation *'s if I type the password wrong, so it seems like it *is* validating.  However, the ValidationSummary that is associated with this Login control never displays any of the logon errors.

My code is like this.  I set the ValidationGroup just like it said in the Walkthrough:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"></asp:Login>
```

Can anyone let me know what I'm missing?

Thanks!
Sandra

Comment: Are you using a master page?

Comment: Yes.  The master page is in the root of the solution.  This Login page is in a sub-folder, for what it's worth.

Comment: Anyone?  Am I supposed to assign the Login1 control to a Validation Group?  It seems that Login1 is not a valid name for a Validation Group, the way it stands in the MSDN example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ValidationGroup` for the child controls will be set to the `UniqueID` of the `Login` control. Since you're using a master page, this will not be the same as the `ID`. Instead, it will be something like `ctl00$Login1`.

The simplest workaround is to set the `ValidationGroup` from the code-behind:

```
ValidationSummary1.ValidationGroup = Login1.UniqueID;
```

Alternatively, you can customize the `LayoutTemplate` and manually specify the `ValidationGroup` on the child validator controls.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was absolutely it - setting it in the code-behind does the trick.